# Показать скрытый элемент при условии, что если выделено два элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть карта, на которую нанесены точки (маркеры):

```css
.map {position: relative; width: 800px; height: 506px;}
.dot {display: block; position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: gold; border-radius: 30px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; line-height: 30px;}
.dot:hover::before {content: ""; position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50px; background-color: gold; animation: animate 1.5s infinite normal ease-out;
}
@keyframes animate {from {transform: scale(0); opacity: .5}to {transform: scale(2); opacity: 0;}}

.aa {top: 440px; left: 260px;}
.bb {top: 320px; left: 380px;}
.cc {top: 260px; left: 240px;}

.win {display: none; position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 200px; width: 200px; height: 50px; background: pink; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;}

.close {position: absolute; top: -1px; right: -1px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px 10px; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lfnZ.jpg">
  <span class="dot aa">A</span>
  <span class="dot bb">B</span>
  <span class="dot cc">C</span>
</div>

<div class="win ab">Окно AB<span class="close">X</span></div>
<div class="win ac">Окно AC<span class="close">X</span></div>

<div class="win ba">Окно BA<span class="close">X</span></div>
<div class="win bc">Окно BC<span class="close">X</span></div>

<div class="win ca">Окно CA<span class="close">X</span></div>
<div class="win cb">Окно CB<span class="close">X</span></div>
```

**Вопрос:** Как мне показать скрытый элемент при условии, что выделены две точки? Более подробно, сценарий следующий:

1. При клике на одну точку (например, на точку `A`) она выделяется. При повторном клике на эту же точку мы снимаем выделение. ⇒ В результате ничего не происходит.

1.1. Выделить точку и снять с нее выделение мы можем, например, с помощью `javascript`, путем добавления/удаления при клике на элемент дополнительного класса:

```js
let items;
let item;
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
  for(let dot of dots) {
    dot.addEventListener('click', () => {
      //for(let it of dots) it.classList.remove('active');
      dot.classList.toggle('active')
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.map {position: relative; width: 800px; height: 506px;}
.dot {display: block; position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: gold; border-radius: 30px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; line-height: 30px;}
.dot:hover::before {content: ""; position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50px; background-color: gold; animation: animate 1.5s infinite normal ease-out;
}
@keyframes animate {from {transform: scale(0); opacity: .5}to {transform: scale(2); opacity: 0;}}

.aa {top: 440px; left: 260px;}
.bb {top: 320px; left: 380px;}
.cc {top: 260px; left: 240px;}

.active {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lfnZ.jpg">
  <span class="dot aa">A</span>
  <span class="dot bb">B</span>
  <span class="dot cc">C</span>
</div>
```

2. При клике на одну точку (например, на точку `A`) она выделяется. Кликаем на другую точку (например, на точку `B`) она тоже выделяется ⇒ В результате показывается скрытый элемент.

2.1. При выделении точек:
`A` и `B` - показывается элемент с классом `.ab`
`A` и `C` - показывается элемент с классом `.ac`
`B` и `A` - показывается элемент с классом `.ba`
`B` и `C` - показывается элемент с классом `.bc`
`C` и `A` - показывается элемент с классом `.ca`
`C` и `B` - показывается элемент с классом `.cb`

3. При клике на крестик (`<span class="close">X</span>`), который есть в каждом скрытом элементе ⇒ элемент скрывается, и с точек, которые выделены, снимаются выделения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сразу появляется вопрос, «как организовать связь между элементами». У вас ключевыми связывающими являются названия классов `class="dot aa"`. Можно, например, взять этот `aa` через какой-нибудь `[...elem.classList].filter(e => e.length == 2)[0]` который отфильтрует и оставит в массиве только классы с названием из двух букв, возьмет [0]-й элемент списка. Но такие манипуляции с названиями классов не очень надежны, т.к. о них можно благополучно забыть (и, например, добавить другие классы из 2-х букв).

Поэтому вынес все необходимые названия в отдельные `data-`атрибуты, но написал код так, чтобы при желании переключиться на логику с названиями классов.

Остается в каком-то массиве собирать кнопки, на которые кликают (значит знать последовательность кликов). А после каждого добавления кнопки, проверять длину массива == 2 ? открыть окно.

В зависимости от  <s>настроения</s>  задачи, код можно организовать сильно по разному.

Вариация:

* На всякий случай обеспечил работу при любой комбинации кликов на кнопки, даже когда окно открыто. Одновременно может открываться только одно окно.

```js
const _o = {
  all: function (selector, root) {
    return (root || document).querySelectorAll(selector);
  },
};

/***/
const KEY = {
  // Вынес использованные data-значения в отдельный объект.
  // Весь код работает на основе строк, выданных отсюда как "ключевые" для
  // элементов: кнопок и окон. При желании можно поменять их на название класса и пр.

  of_win: function(node) {
    return node.dataset.key;
  },

  for_win: function(dot1, dot2) {
    return dot1.dataset.key + '_' + dot2.dataset.key;
  },
};

const WIN = new class { /* Всплывающие окна */

  constructor() {
    this.map = this.__init__node_map();
    this.now_open = null;

    this.__init__listeners();
    // __init__ не имеет специального значения. Но быстрее бросается в глаза.
  }

  __init__node_map() {
    let map = {/*
      'ab': div.win.ab (node),
      'ac': div.win.ac (node),
      ...
    */};

    for (let node of _o.all('.win')) map[KEY.of_win(node)] = node;

    return map;
  }

  __init__listeners() {
    let SELF = this;

    /***/
    for (let btn of _o.all('.win .close')) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', win_close);
    }

    function win_close() {
      SELF.close();
      DOT.unselect_all();
    }
  }

  any_open() {
    return !!this.now_open; // !! приводит к логическому типу.
    // now_open - или null или ссылка на открытый HTML элемент;
    // !!null → false   !!HTMLэлемент → true
  }

  open(selected_1 /* node */, selected_2 /* node */) {
    if (this.any_open()) this.close();

    let key = KEY.for_win(selected_1, selected_2);
    let win = this.map[key];

    win.classList.add('active');

    this.now_open = win;
  }

  close() {
    this.now_open.classList.remove('active');
    this.now_open = null;
  }
};

const DOT = new class { /* Кнопки на карте */

  constructor() {
    this.selected = [/* nodeList */];

    this.__init__listeners();
  }

  __init__listeners() {
    let SELF = this;

    /***/
    for (let dot of _o.all('.dot')) {
      dot.addEventListener('click', toggle_dot);
    }

    function toggle_dot() {
      SELF.toggle(this);
    }
  }

  /***/
  toggle(elem) {
    let is_active = elem.classList.contains('active');
    this[is_active ? 'unselect' : 'select'](elem);
  }

  select(elem) {
    let selected = this.selected;

    elem.classList.add('active');
    selected.push(elem);

    while (selected.length > 2) this.unselect(selected.shift());

    if (selected.length == 2) WIN.open(...selected);
    // (*) Справка: « ...spread, ...rest операторы »
  }

  unselect(elem) {
    let selected = this.selected;

    elem.classList.remove('active');

    let index = selected.indexOf(elem);
    if (index != -1) selected.splice(index, 1);

    if (selected.length < 2 && WIN.any_open()) WIN.close();
  }

  unselect_all() {
    let sel = this.selected;

    for (let i = sel.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      this.unselect(sel[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.map {position: relative; width: 800px; height: 506px;}
.dot {display: block; position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: gold; border-radius: 30px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; line-height: 30px;}
.dot:hover::before {content: ""; position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50px; background-color: gold; animation: animate 1.5s infinite normal ease-out;
}
@keyframes animate {from {transform: scale(0); opacity: .5}to {transform: scale(2); opacity: 0;}}

.aa {top: 440px; left: 260px;}
.bb {top: 320px; left: 380px;}
.cc {top: 260px; left: 240px;}

/* Добавлены стили: */
.dot {
    user-select: none;
}

.dot.active {background-color: red;}

.win {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  text-align: center;
  background: #fffa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}

.win.active {
  display: block;
}

.close {
  color: red;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lfnZ.jpg">
  <span class="dot aa" data-key="a">A</span>
  <span class="dot bb" data-key="b">B</span>
  <span class="dot cc" data-key="c">C</span>
</div>

<div class="win ab" data-key="a_b">Окно AB<span class="close">X</span></div>
<div class="win ac" data-key="a_c">Окно AC<span class="close">X</span></div>

<div class="win ba" data-key="b_a">Окно BA<span class="close">X</span></div>
<div class="win bc" data-key="b_c">Окно BC<span class="close">X</span></div>

<div class="win ca" data-key="c_a">Окно CA<span class="close">X</span></div>
<div class="win cb" data-key="c_b">Окно CB<span class="close">X</span></div>
```

Для перехода на вариант с названиями классов, можно заменть функции в объекте KEY:

```
const KEY = {

  of_win: function(node) {
    // выдает название первого класса из двух букв.
    return [...node.classList].find(e => e.length == 2); // 'ab'
  },

  for_win: function(dot1, dot2) {    
    let key1 = [...dot1.classList].find(e => e.length == 2); // 'aa'
    let key2 = [...dot2.classList].find(e => e.length == 2); // 'bb'
    return key1[0] + key2[0]; // ('aa'[0] → 'a') + ('bb'[0] → 'b') → 'ab'
  },

};
```

```js
const _o = {
  all: function (selector, root) {
    return (root || document).querySelectorAll(selector);
  },
};

/***/
const KEY = {

  of_win: function(node) {
    // выдает название первого класса из двух букв.
    return [...node.classList].find(e => e.length == 2); // 'ab'
  },

  for_win: function(dot1, dot2) {    
    let key1 = [...dot1.classList].find(e => e.length == 2); // 'aa'
    let key2 = [...dot2.classList].find(e => e.length == 2); // 'bb'
    return key1[0] + key2[0]; // ('aa'[0] → 'a') + ('bb'[0] → 'b') → 'ab'
  },

};

const WIN = new class { /* Всплывающие окна */

  constructor() {
    this.map = this.__init__node_map();
    this.now_open = null;

    this.__init__listeners();
    // __init__ не имеет специального значения. Но быстрее бросается в глаза.
  }

  __init__node_map() {
    let map = {/*
      'ab': div.win.ab (node),
      'ac': div.win.ac (node),
      ...
    */};

    for (let node of _o.all('.win')) map[KEY.of_win(node)] = node;

    return map;
  }

  __init__listeners() {
    let SELF = this;

    /***/
    for (let btn of _o.all('.win .close')) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', win_close);
    }

    function win_close() {
      SELF.close();
      DOT.unselect_all();
    }
  }

  any_open() {
    return !!this.now_open; // !! приводит к логическому типу.
    // now_open - или null или ссылка на открытый HTML элемент;
    // !!null → false   !!HTMLэлемент → true
  }

  open(selected_1 /* node */, selected_2 /* node */) {
    if (this.any_open()) this.close();

    let key = KEY.for_win(selected_1, selected_2);
    let win = this.map[key];

    win.classList.add('active');

    this.now_open = win;
  }

  close() {
    this.now_open.classList.remove('active');
    this.now_open = null;
  }
};

const DOT = new class { /* Кнопки на карте */

  constructor() {
    this.selected = [/* nodeList */];

    this.__init__listeners();
  }

  __init__listeners() {
    let SELF = this;

    /***/
    for (let dot of _o.all('.dot')) {
      dot.addEventListener('click', toggle_dot);
    }

    function toggle_dot() {
      SELF.toggle(this);
    }
  }

  /***/
  toggle(elem) {
    let is_active = elem.classList.contains('active');
    this[is_active ? 'unselect' : 'select'](elem);
  }

  select(elem) {
    let selected = this.selected;

    elem.classList.add('active');
    selected.push(elem);

    while (selected.length > 2) this.unselect(selected.shift());

    if (selected.length == 2) WIN.open(...selected);
    // (*) Справка: « ...spread, ...rest операторы »
  }

  unselect(elem) {
    let selected = this.selected;

    elem.classList.remove('active');

    let index = selected.indexOf(elem);
    if (index != -1) selected.splice(index, 1);

    if (selected.length < 2 && WIN.any_open()) WIN.close();
  }

  unselect_all() {
    let sel = this.selected;

    for (let i = sel.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      this.unselect(sel[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.map {position: relative; width: 800px; height: 506px;}
.dot {display: block; position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: gold; border-radius: 30px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; line-height: 30px;}
.dot:hover::before {content: ""; position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50px; background-color: gold; animation: animate 1.5s infinite normal ease-out;
}
@keyframes animate {from {transform: scale(0); opacity: .5}to {transform: scale(2); opacity: 0;}}

.aa {top: 440px; left: 260px;}
.bb {top: 320px; left: 380px;}
.cc {top: 260px; left: 240px;}

/* Добавлены стили: */
.dot {
    user-select: none;
}

.dot.active {background-color: red;}

.win {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  text-align: center;
  background: #fffa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}

.win.active {
  display: block;
}

.close {
  color: red;
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lfnZ.jpg">
  <span class="dot aa">A</span>
  <span class="dot bb">B</span>
  <span class="dot cc">C</span>
</div>

<div class="win ab">Окно AB<span class="close">X</span></div>
<div class="win ac">Окно AC<span class="close">X</span></div>

<div class="win ba">Окно BA<span class="close">X</span></div>
<div class="win bc">Окно BC<span class="close">X</span></div>

<div class="win ca">Окно CA<span class="close">X</span></div>
<div class="win cb">Окно CB<span class="close">X</span></div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' Дратути, добавлено в конце ответа. Там пара строчек) Но будет проблема, если кнопок окажется больше 26 (`zz`...).

Comment: @Sevastopol' Да) Можно придумать танцы с бубном, чтобы всё-таки надежно организовать это с классами. Например, "редкие" названия классов у кнопок, а-ля `a-_-a`, `b-_-b` и их комбо у окон `a-_-a___b-_-b`, такое наверняка не будет путаться ни с чем другим. Но проще прописать обычные строки в data) Хотя, в общем случае у data тоже есть проблема `abc` - это `a + bc` или `ab + c`. Внес небольшое изменение в data-окон и функцию `KEY.for_win`, `'ab' → 'a_b'`. С разделителем уже точно не будет путаницы.